# jq: merge array files is splitting the arrays

Tags: jq

I've several json files in my directory:

```
/home/jeusdi/projects/salut/mpi/hes-mpi-api-service/mock-expectations/
├── cobertures-expectation.json
├── comunitats-expectations.json
├── localitats-expectations.json
├── ocupacions-expectations.json
├── paisos-expectations.json
├── provincies-expectation.json
└── tipusvia-expectation.json
```

Each one is an array. I need to merge them into a single json array file.

I tried to use `-s` option like this:

```
$ jq -s '.[]' \
  ~/projects/salut/mpi/hes-mpi-api-service/mock-expectations/*.json > \
  ~/projects/workarea/salut/mpi/mockserver/config/expectations.json
```

Nevertheless, when I get the length of merged file, I'm getting:

```
$ jq length ~/projects/workarea/salut/mpi/mockserver/config/expectations.json                                                                      
1
1
142
8
3
1
1
```

I've also tried this command:

```
$ jq -s . \
  ~/projects/salut/mpi/hes-mpi-api-service/mock-expectations/*.json > \
  ~/projects/workarea/salut/mpi/mockserver/config/expectations.json
```

Nevertheless length command is getting:

```
$ jq length ~/projects/workarea/salut/mpi/mockserver/config/expectations.json                                                                  
7
```

Any ideas about how to merge all of those files into a single one json array file?

Comment: Use `jq -s add`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the following file structure:

```
==> first.json <==
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

==> second.json <==
[ 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]

==> third.json <==
[ 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 ]
```

Then, we can create a single array containing those 3 files by using the following JQ command:

```
jq -s add first.json second.json third.json
```

Result:

```json
[
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6,
  7,
  8,
  9,
  10,
  11,
  12,
  13,
  14,
  15
]
```